# How do I convert babel + terser workflow to webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, terser

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- src/internal-logic.js
- src/header.js
- src/footer.js
- package.json
```

Here is a section of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npx babel --watch src --out-dir dist --presets react-app/prod",
    "build": "npx babel src --out-dir dist --presets react-app/prod",
    "minify": "npx terser -c -m -o dist/common.min.js -- dist/header.js dist/footer.js dist/internal-logic.js"
  },
```

When deploying this code I run the following commands

```
npm run build
npm run minify
```

This generates a file called `common.min.js` which I use in a few projects.

What I would like to do is to make a single build command by using webpack. How can I go about doing that?

**UPDATE**

I have created the following webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'common.js': [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/internal-logic.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/footer.js'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/header.js')
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
         rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
                }
              }
            }
         ]
     },
};
```

This works

Comment: `mode: "production"` will apply terser by default.

Comment: That's what I realised.